# Swift White Screen upon returning from SafariWebController

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

When I open a safari view controller and then return to my app (when "Done" is pressed), my app renders a blank/white screen instead of the content for that view.

The code below is the code I have tried using in an empty view - the issue happens no matter where I try in my app.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class SavedViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if let link = URL(string: "https://google.com"){
            let myrequest = SFSafariViewController(url: link)
            myrequest.delegate = self
            present(myrequest, animated:true)
        }
    }

    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The website loads fine, its when I return to my app that the blank screen appears. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine.
You just created new UIViewController this way, UIViewController by default have black background. So when you press Done you just come back from SafariViewController to you SavedViewController (UIViewController). 
Probably You are looking for UIWebView solution https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview.
If u want only display SafariViewController do it as function from your ViewController, You don't need to create new File with UIViewController class to do it.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class SavedViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    view.backgroundColor = .gray
    setupViews()
}

func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}

private func setupViews(){
    view.addSubview(openSafariButton)
    openSafariButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOpenSafariButtonTap), for: .touchUpInside)
    openSafariButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width, height: 60)
}

@objc func handleOpenSafariButtonTap(){
    if let link = URL(string: "https://google.com"){
        let myrequest = SFSafariViewController(url: link)
        myrequest.delegate = self
        present(myrequest, animated:true)
    }
}

let openSafariButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("openSafari", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    return button
}()

}
```

That is what i mean.

You can add function:

```
    private func openSafariLink(link: String){
    if let link = URL(string: link){
        let myrequest = SFSafariViewController(url: link)
        present(myrequest, animated:true)
    }
}
```

And call it from any place like that:

```
openSafariLink(link: "https://google.com")
```

This way fits more for Your solution.

Comment: Nowhere have I mentioned a black background - I see white. There is content in my UIViewController, so why isnt that showing? I need the 'done' functionality because my app opens external links but it should be able to come back directly into the app - a SafariViewController allows this by default so why would I reinvent the wheel? Plus what you have linked is deprecated.

Comment: You provide source code. As it is new ViewController witch open SafariViewController on ViewDidLoad. I mean You should call code as function instead of opening new ViewController and calling it from ViewDidLoad

Comment: And ye I know that UIWebView is deprecated i just provide it as is kind of solution, so u can let us know what u are looking for. (And u see white background, because you probably added it by storyboard)

Comment: If I want to use this inside a tableviewcontroller, will this behaviour still work as expected or will they need to be separated from each other?

Comment: It should works fine. U can use it on button tap or didselect tableView method, I will provide some extra code so at the and of answer, it will make it simpler.

Comment: And if u are not using any delegate methods for SFSafariViewController you don't need to use it at all. So u don't even need to add SFSafariViewControllerDelegate.

Comment: tried tested and works perfectly - thanks for your detailed help